# Trying to load two autocomplete csv databases in Python (one gui). Is it possible? Getting an error every time I try

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, autocomplete

This is at the bottom of my code:

```
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window(autocompleteList3, autocompleteList2)
    w.show()
```

I need to be able to import both autocompleteList3 and autocompleteList2. However, when I do this, I get "TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given." It'll only allow me to use either autocompleteList3 or autocompleteList2 alone.

Here's my autocomplete function (if this is helpful):

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, cList):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                 
        self.cList = cList
        self.Input_5.addItems(sorted(cList.keys())) 
        self.Input_5.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)


class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, cList):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                 
        self.cList = cList
        self.Input_7.addItems(sorted(cList.keys())) 
        self.Input_7.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        self.Input_19.setText(self.cList[text][0])
        self.Input_29.setText(self.cList[text][1])
        self.Input_30.setText(self.cList[text][2])
        self.Input_18.setText(self.cList[text][3])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText2(self, text):
        self.Input_19.setText(self.cList[text][0])
        self.Input_29.setText(self.cList[text][1])
        self.Input_30.setText(self.cList[text][2])
        self.Input_18.setText(self.cList[text][3])
```

And finally, here's autocompleteList3 (2 looks the same):

```
autocompleteList3 = {
'': ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
    'two': ['3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', 'test55'],
    'one': ['3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', '3332', '234234', 'test55', 'test55'],
}


with open('boxes.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        autocompleteList2[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19]]
```

Anybody know how to make this work? I need to have both autocomplete functions pulling from csv files in the same window. :/

Comment: two ways: either merge the two lists together first, or adjust your init code to merge multiple lists in the init.  The first suggestion is probably easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. See below.

I had to get away from cList and assign autocompleteList2 in its place. Works perfectly. The try except pass is there to prevent crashing when dealing /w blank cells.

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def **init**(self, cList):
        super().**init**()

```
    self.setupUi(self)                                 

    self.cList = cList
    self.Input_5.addItems((cList.keys())) 
    self.Input_5.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText2)

    self.autocompleteList2 = autocompleteList2
    self.Input_7.addItems((autocompleteList2.keys())) 
    self.Input_7.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def onActivatedText2(self, text):
    try:
        self.Input_19.setText(self.cList[text][0])
        self.Input_29.setText(self.cList[text][1])
        self.Input_30.setText(self.cList[text][2])
        self.Input_18.setText(self.cList[text][3])
        self.Input_15.setText(self.cList[text][4])
        self.Input_14.setText(self.cList[text][5])
        self.Input_13.setText(self.cList[text][6])
        self.Input_25.setText(self.cList[text][7])
        self.Input_20.setText(self.cList[text][8])
        self.Input_21.setText(self.cList[text][9])
        self.Input_22.setText(self.cList[text][10])
        self.Input_24.setText(self.cList[text][11])
        self.Input_26.setText(self.cList[text][12])
        self.Input_28.setText(self.cList[text][13])
        self.Input_23.setText(self.cList[text][14])
        self.Input_27.setText(self.cList[text][15])
        self.Input_31.setText(self.cList[text][16])
        self.Input_32.setText(self.cList[text][17])
        self.Input_33.setText(self.cList[text][18])
    except: pass

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def onActivatedText(self, text):
    try:
        self.Input_6.setText(self.autocompleteList2[text][0])
        self.Input_8.setText(self.autocompleteList2[text][1])
        self.Input_9.setText(self.autocompleteList2[text][2])
    except: pass
```